# Property 'delegate' object not found on type 'UIViewController *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am getting the following error when i run the project, indicated in the line `secView.delegate=self;`
How can i solve the above problem? Thanks!

> Property 'delegate'  object not found on type 'UIViewController *'

myViewController.h

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,secondViewControllerDelegate>
- (IBAction)popBookmarkTable:(id)sender;
```

myViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)popBookmarkTable:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *secView = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bookmarkViewController"];
[self presentViewController:secView animated:YES completion:nil];

    secView.delegate=self;
}

- (void)passData:(NSString *)data
{

          _addressBar.text=data;

    }
```

bookmarkViewController.h

```
@protocol secondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)passData:(NSString *)data;

@end
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<secondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *a;
@end
```

bookmarkViewController.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
              if ([indexPath row]==0) {
                   _a=(NSString *)cell.textLabel.text;
                  [_delegate passData:_a];
                  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


              }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare `secView`, you define it as `UIViewController *secView` - i.e. a plain `UIViewController`. So, it doesn't have any of your custom properties as far as the compiler is concerned.

You need to declare it as the specific class type that it will be at runtime:

```
BookmarkViewController *secView = ...;
```

Comment: Just replace  
UIViewController  *menuVC =  [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
on the 
MenuViewController  *menuVC =  [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 1):

You need to further scope your secView object. `UIViewController` does not declare the delegate property, but your protocol does. If you're sure the view controller will implement that protocol, try this:

```
UIViewController<secondViewControllerDelegate> *secView = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bookmarkViewController"];
```